# How to make two fields unique of same model in django

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, mysql-connector-python

I'm using DispensingUnit class name and having two fields `'keypad1_sr_no_hw'` and `'keypad2_sr_no_hw'`.

How can we compare the uniqueness of these two fields meaning two fields never having same combination ofvalues?

Used this `unique_together`, but its not working.

```
class Meta:
        unique_together = (("keypad1_sr_no_hw", "keypad2_sr_no_hw",))

class DispensingUnit(models.Model):
        keypad1_sr_no_hw = models.CharField(U'Keypad 1', max_length=20 ,)
   keypad2_sr_no_hw = models.CharField(U'Keypad 2', max_length=20,)
```

value in `keypad1_sr_no_hw` is `KP2019310001` and in `keypad2_sr_no_hw` `KP2019310001` and still get saved.
I expect that when both the values are same it will show error and values do not get stored.

Comment: Should all values for keypad1_sr_no_hw and keypad2_sr_no_hw be unique accross all DispensingUnits? Or can they not be the same for one instance of DispensingUnit?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding the save method, do something along the line

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.keypad1_sr_no_hw == self.keypad2_sr_no_hw:
        raise ValidationError("keypad1_sr_no_hw and keypad2_sr_no_hw have same values")
    return super(DispensingUnit, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I know It might not be what you are looking for, but it will do the job for you, I am not sure that any built-in django property exists that can compare multiple fields for Uniqueness.